# Report Viewer - scaling issue with system DPI change

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

I have a Winforms application (in Visual Studio 2010) that contains a Report Viewer control that previews and prints an A4 size report.

One user has his Windows font size set to 150% (i.e. a system DPI change) and when he runs the report, it is shrunk to 2/3 size in both the Report Viewer preview and the printed report.

The AutoScaleMode property of the form containing the Report Viewer is set to "Font", although it doesn't seem to affect the report if I change this.

This isn't a font (missing/scaling) issue as I have an example program to demonstrate the problem that contains nothing but a rectangle that takes up the whole page.

It seems I need some way to specify in the report itself that it should be rendered at 96dpi regardless of the system dpi setting, but can't see anywhere that I can specify this. What am I missing?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Same issue but in 2012.  Print preview and the printed report both contain shrunk contents.  It is like a calculation to compensate for the increased screen DPI has gone wrong.  Did you find any way to fix this?

Comment: @Gavin - no, I didn't find a fix. As a workaround, selecting "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" in the compatibility settings for the .exe seems to solve the problem (this is on Windows 7).

Comment: Thanks @davidl I now at least have a fix for users with this issue.

Comment: @davidl Have you tried setting the AutoScaleMode to Dpi and adding a piece of code from this [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b788f7d-f072-48de-b15c-62d73aa8b5e0/report-viewer-for-windows-forms-displaying-23-page-size?forum=winforms)?

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same problem. WinForms ReportViewer is already DPI aware and will do its own scaling. You just have to tell the system that your application is DPI aware so that the system doesn't try to scale it after.

Add a manifest to your application if you haven't already, then inside the  tag, add the following:

```
  <asmv3:application  xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" >
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
```

You can also use an API function SetProcessDPIAware, but it is recommended against: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633543.aspx

Comment: I have a Win Forms `ReportViewer` embedded in a WPF application using the `WindowsFormsHost` control.  WPF applications always register themselves as DPI-aware, but the `ReportViewer` is exhibiting this problem behavior, so this solution doesn't help.

Comment: Where would I put this code?  I added it to the bottom of the appname.exe.manifest file and got the error "Activation failed due to a Windows Side-by-Side error."

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem which I have been trying to fix for days!

Comment: This was a life saver! to add a manifest just select add new item and then, pick manifest in your project

Comment: For me the `asmv3` tag name was not needed, I just added a new manifest by right clicking on the project -> Add new item -> Application Manifest (Windows Only). the generated manifest already contains the `dpiAware` setting, you just need to uncomment it

Comment: @ScottWhitlock: I know it's been a long time, but I am in your same exact situation... did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Master_T: nope.  The users have to change their resolution, then log out and back into windows for it to take effect.

Answer (score -1):

As a complimentary answer to what @JoMan said (since I can't comment on his post) bear in mind that you can manually scale up the UI elements in your app relatively simply. So leave your application DPI aware (so that your system doesn't distort the printed results) as JOMan suggested. You could use something like this...

```
Using g As System.Drawing.Graphics = WindowsForm.CreateGraphics
 Dim sngScaleFactor As Single = 1
 Dim sngFontFactor As Single = 1 

 If (graphics.Dpix >= 96) Then
      sngScaleFactor = (graphics.Dpix / 96) - 0.25
      sngFontFactor = (graphics.Dpix / 96) - 0.25
 End If

 If WindowsForm.AutoScaleDimensions = WindowsForm.CurrentAutoScaleDimensions Then
            WindowsForm.Scale(sngScaleFactor)
            For Each child As Control In WindowsForm.Controls
                ScaleFontRecursively(child, sngFontFactor)
            Next
 End If
End Using
```

I'm sure many people will argue (rightly!) that you generally don't want to detect DPI and manually scale yourself, but the bug with the dpi autoscaling screwing up printed microsoft reports is still outstanding as of 2018, so this provides an easy work around.

Comment: Where would this code go? In the report viewer form in the on load event, maybe?