# RDLC not Displaying Properly

Tags: vb.net, winforms, report, reporting, rdlc

I have a RDLC Report that should display texts as is. In my expectation the report should just display everything as what I see in the Designer.

> Designer View:
>
> [image]

I want the report to be previewed in the `"Print Preview"` just the way it is in the `designer`. I have set the `margins` to **`0`**, have the `InteractiveSize` and `PageSize` equal *(8in width and 11in height)*.

> But when I run the program and go to its print preview, this is how it
>   shows up.[image]

There seems to be a lot more white space on the right side *(Highlighted in Yellow)* which I did not expect to be there since I have set the properties right. Or As I think it is.

What could I have been missing here? I have properly installed reportviewer, I have set the properties even the report's body, and I do not alter the sizes programmatically, the size should just use as what was defined in the properties.

> Body Properties:
>
> [image]
>
> Report Properties:
>
> [image]

Comment: Win10? If so, did you declare your application to be DPI Aware?  See: [Report Viewer - scaling issue with system DPI change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411240/report-viewer-scaling-issue-with-system-dpi-change/27966774#27966774)

Comment: I can't try this out atm (since, I'm far from the project/file), but I will try later. I have read the answer and the article, can this be placed, anywhere inside the <assembly ...> tag? like,maybe before the closing </assembly> tag?

Comment: Placing it right before the closing tag `</assembly>` is fine.  If you are using VS2015 or newer, there should be a commented out block in the manifest created for a project when you click on the "View Window Settings" button under the Project Properties->Application Tab that you can enable.

Comment: @TnTinMn I just applied it and got several errors. `Unable to apply publish properties for item "de\microsoft.reportviewer.winforms.resources".` and `Overlapping report items are not supported in all renderers.`

Comment: I applied it, removed the orphaned resources, and encountered `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll` error.

Comment: @TnTinMn thanks for the DPI hint. It fixed the bug, but unfortunately the report works great now but all other forms are now out of whack.

Comment: If by _out of whack_ you mean that they appear smaller than before, you could try changing the `Form.AutoScaleMode` property to `DPI` from the designer default of `Font`; your mileage may vary though.  Also add `<appSettings><add key="EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing" value="true" /></appSettings>` to the app.config file.  However this is a whole other topic and would be best addressed in a new question.  Also, I'm going to mark this question for closure as a duplicate.