# Microsoft RDLC Report background image how to fill page

Tags: vb.net, desktop-application, rdlc

I have a background image sizing issue with a RDLC report. Does anyone know how to size a background for a RDLC report written in VS (vb.net C# responses are fine) desktop application, the report is running in local mode. When I initially created the report was fine text boxes appeared in the correct position but when I run it with a different resolution/and or Scale/ or export it's a mess. Lots of answers about the issue, but I want to know where exactly can I interoperate the page size and resize the image, custom class, custom code.

The image is an embedded image set as background on the body.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, the application is to manage Covid in a third world country and against the clock with delta.
[RDLC Report background Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q6P7.png)

Comment: There is currently no working solution to fix the scaling issue on `WinForm.ReportViewer`.  However a possible [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68428344/6670491) for printing exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the page size of the background image according to the paper size of your report. Example: If the `paper size is 8.5x11 inches` then the `background image` must have the size of `8.5x11 inches`.

Comment: Thanks your your reply,Yes I tried that in different combination's. the difference is like 25% of the page is missing when you print from a different screen resolution. It's like the display resolution adjusts the picture dpi which adjusts the image size. I wrote it all using 3840x2160 with 150% Scaling might redo it at 1080 at 100% scaling and see if the issue goes the other way. Have lots of forms to do so need it bullet proof.