# RDLC with .NET Core 5.0 throws error in production if I use expressions inside report creation, works fine in development

Tags: rdlc

I'm using RDLC to create reports with my .NET Core Web API. I spent an entire week creating 3 reports using lots of expressions. Now after publishing the application on IIS every report fails with error

> An error occurred during local report processing.;An unexpected error
> occurred in Report Processing.Object reference not set to an instance
> of an object

The report works fine in development. After lots of research I found the issue is with expressions. I have been struggling to find a solution for almost a day searching the entire web. Many people suggested that this is the limitation of RDLC and we can't use expressions. Without expressions there is no use of this tool for me. I can't afford to spend another week to re-create those reports using another tool. In fact I don't even know what else can I use instead of RDLC to create reports.

Any suggestion to fix these issues or an alternative to RDLC will be life saving for me....
It's been a pain to use this unstable tool, but unfortunately I'm stuck in this.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share the links which tells you this is a limitation?

Comment: I found it here... https://github.com/amh1979/AspNetCore.Reporting/issues/4   And also on Stackoverflow but can't find link now

Comment: I see... That's the risk of using non official RDLC runtime. Do you need to show reports on web page? If you only need to render the reports, you can wrap the codes in a `.NET Framework` library with `RDLC 2015 runtime` and reference as dll from .NET 5. It would look a bit like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68524459/6670491)

Comment: @HardcoreGamer thanks for your comments. I don't need to show report on a web page, just render the report and show as a downloadable PDF or directly to the printer. I will check the link, I haven't done it before...but if you have any other useful links please share.

Comment: @HardcoreGamer I looked at the link, unfortunately I didn't understand very clearly how it works. Mine is a .NET core web API and I just need to render a report. Please can you share a simple project on how this works, or I have created a sample API project and shared here (https://github.com/sa4git/WebAPI_RDLC) please...please if you can.. modify this to add your method.

Comment: You need to add another project in your solution in Visual Studio. `Such project should use  .NET Framework 4.8`, then write you report generation code in that 4.8 project and render the RDLC reports by calling its' functions. .`NET 4.8` version of `RDLC designer` is [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001) and `runtime` is [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496).

Comment: Found and tested a method, seems like an additional solution is not needed. Please check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69430852/6670491).

Answer (score 1):

Having .NET Core work with library from .NET framework is painful to say the least.

Thanks for the recompiled WinForms [library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReportViewerCore.NETCore/) provided by `lkosson`.
I managed to make this work but it looks like bandage fix more then anything.

**Very Important Note!! This solution make use of WPF, WinForms version of RDLC. This limit the .NET 5 solution to Windows build only.** (I can't make Web version to work, maybe someone else can)

---

**1. Update `.NET 5` project settings**

Unload the `.NET 5 project`

Right click and Edit .csproj

[image]

Update/Add 3 lines in property group as following:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    --><TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Net_Core_5._0</RootNamespace>
    --><UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    --><EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>true</EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Reload the project

---

**2. Add NuGet Packages**

[image]

Add and install the following packages:

`Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common`

`Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms`

`ReportViewerCore.WinForms`

[image]

[image]

---

**3. Use .NET version's function to generate Report**

This is an example for your reference,

```
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;

namespace NET_4._8_RDLC_Lib
{
    public class ReportGenerator
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// .NET Core use this function to render reports
        /// </summary>
        public static byte[] RenderReport(String reportPath, Dictionary<string, DataTable> data, string format)
        {

            Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer v1 = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer();
            v1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

            //Add all datasource to the Report
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DataTable> pair in data)
            {
                Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource ds = new ReportDataSource(pair.Key, pair.Value);

                v1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds);

            }

            v1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
            v1.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath;

            return v1.LocalReport.Render(format: format, deviceInfo: "");
        }
    }
}
```

The file is just inside the `bytes` array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for creating the above solution, It works well, but I'm not sure how this can be referenced by my .NET Core 5.0 Web API project. your statement "This limit the .NET 5 solution to Windows build only" means it only works with windows projects?

Comment: @MSBI-Geek Just add this within your .NET Core 5.0 Web API, additional project referencing is not needed. Or is additional projects is what you preferred? About the windows thing, .NET Core 5.0 AFAIK can be deployed to different platform, for instance, Linux. but since this solution use WinForm version of Report Viewer and WPF techs, the target framework has been set to `net5.0-windows`, which mean it can only deploy to windows platform.

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it now, I'm only targeting Windows so that shouldn't be a problem. I was worried that the solution only works for windows forms app but not web API. Now it is clear. I don't need another project if it works in the same project. Thanks a heap for your help.